# How to use take_while with futures::Stream?

Tags: rust, future

I'm trying to understand what syntax should I use for [`take_while()`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#method.take_while) with `futures::Stream;` crate (0.1.25). Here's a piece of code ([on playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ff7b38df9512d7c41f641872ffd2cd74)):

```
use futures::{stream, Stream}; // 0.1.25

fn into_many(i: i32) -> impl Stream<Item = i32, Error = ()> {
    stream::iter_ok(0..i)
}

fn main() {
    println!("start:");
    let _ = into_many(10)
        // .take_while(|x| { x < 10 })
        .map(|x| {
            println!("number={}", x);
            x
        })
        .wait();
    for _ in foo {} // ← this (by @mcarton)

    println!("finish:");
}
```

The main goal is to determine the right combinations of operators/commands to run the presented playground successfully with `take_while`: when I uncomment my take_while() it says

```
expected &i32, found integral variable | help: consider borrowing here: &10
```

and if I put a reference, it says:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound bool: futures::future::Future is not satisfied
```

which is weird to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`take_while` expects the closure to return a future, or something that can be converted to a future. `bool` doesn't implement `IntoFuture`, so you have to wrap it in a future instead. [`future::ok`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1/futures/future/fn.ok.html) returns a future that is immediately ready with the specified value.

```
use futures::{future, stream, Stream}; // 0.1.25

fn into_many(i: i32) -> impl Stream<Item = i32, Error = ()> {
    stream::iter_ok(0..i)
}

fn main() {
    println!("start:");
    let foo = into_many(10)
        .take_while(|&x| { future::ok(x < 10) })
        .map(|x| {
            println!("number={}", x);
            x
        })
        .wait();

    for _ in foo {}

    println!("finish:");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`wait` returns an iterator version of the stream, but that iterator remains lazy, which means you need to iterate it to actually execute your closure:

```rust
use futures::{stream, Stream}; // 0.1.25

fn into_many(i: i32) -> impl Stream<Item = i32, Error = ()> {
    stream::iter_ok(0..i)
}

fn main() {
    println!("start:");
    let foo = into_many(10)
        // .take_while(|x| { x < 10 })
        .map(|x| {
            println!("number={}", x);
            x
        })
        .wait();

    for _ in foo {} // ← this

    println!("finish:");
}
```

([link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9510d39e135e99a5391f6aff89059d8d))

Comment: looks great! There's still one problem, though: when I uncomment my `take_while()` it says `expected &i32, found integral variable | help: consider borrowing here: &5` and if I put a reference, it says `error[E0277]: the trait bound bool: futures::future::Future is not satisfied` which is weird to me.